# new gui components not displaying in netbeans

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans

I started a Netbeans project a couple of weeks ago where I made a GUI.  I came back to it today and added a JComboBox to my source code.  However, when I run the program, my new combo box and all of my other editions to the code do not appear and nothing changes.  It just keeps running my older version of the gui.  Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

Comment: thank you for helping my noobish self @nachokk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Execute `clean & build` command.

> Once you have written and test run your application, you can use the
>   Clean and Build command to build your application for deployment. When
>   you use the Clean and Build command, the IDE runs a build script that
>   performs the following tasks: Deletes any previously compiled files
>   and other build outputs. Recompiles the application and builds a JAR
>   file containing the compiled files. To build your application: Choose
>   Run > Clean and Build Project.

Source [here](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/quickstart.html)